# Can't print the inital number in perl

Tags: perl

My Perl code is not executed from the initial number.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print "SrepAring inpCKut filYes\n";

$incr=0.25;
$dist=3.0;
$inti=3.0;

my $filename = 'job-1.sh';

open (my $BATCHFILE, '>', "$filename");

while ($dist < 15) {
    $dist += $incr;
    $inti = $dist - 0.25;
    print $BATCHFILE
"
YOYO -O -i min_mdin.$dist -o min_mdout.$dist -p TATA -c prod.rst.$inti -r min.rst.$dist
"
}

close ($BATCHFILE);
```

```
YOYO -O -i min_mdin.3 -o min_mdout.3 -p TATA -c prod.rst.2.75 -r min.rst.3

YOYO -O -i min_mdin.3.25 -o min_mdout.3.25 -p TATA -c prod.rst.3 -r min.rst.3.25

YOYO -O -i min_mdin.3.5 -o min_mdout.3.5 -p TATA -c prod.rst.3.25 -r min.rst.3.5
```

Comment: What output do you get? What do you expect instead?

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`. Also, you can stop using `-w`: The last perl that didn't support `use warnings` didn't allow 3-argument `open` either.

Comment: What about '>>' ?

Comment: I want :YOYO -O -i min_mdin.3 -o min_mdout.3 -p TATA -c prod.rst.2.75 -r min.rst.3

YOYO -O -i min_mdin.3.25 -o min_mdout.3.25 -p TATA -c prod.rst.3 -r min.rst.3.25

Comment: But using this codew i get : YOYO -O -i min_mdin.3.25 -o min_mdout.3.25 -p TATA -c prod.rst.3 -r min.rst.3.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the value before it changes, put the `print` before the assignment.

```
while ($dist < 15) {
    print $BATCHFILE "\nYOYO -O -i min_mdin.$dist -o min_mdout.$dist -p TATA -c prod.rst.$inti -r min.rst.$dist\n";
    $dist += $incr;
    $inti = $dist - 0.25;
}
```

Comment: I have not understood your reply. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: You first change the value, then print. Try printing first, then changing the value.

Comment: Sir, may you edit my code? Actually, I am very new in Perl code.